# Convert String Data Time to long Milliseconds: Scala

Tags: scala, datetime, type-conversion

How can I get long milliseconds from String Data Time? I tried using as:

```scala
val desiredTime = "3/20/2017 16:5:45"
System.getTimeInMillis(desiredTime)
```

I found solutions in Java which I tried in Scala, but could not get the desired result. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you have a string you need to specify the format, for available options, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). I tried to infer your format from your example but it could be that it should be slightly different.

```
val desiredTime = "3/20/2017 16:5:45"

val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("M/dd/yyyy HH:m:ss")
val time = format.parse(desiredTime).getTime()
print(time)
```

This will give you 1489997145000 as a result.

Answer (score 1):

> val desiredTime = "3/20/2017 16:5:45"

'desiredTime' is a string.
A string needs to be converted to a Date Time representation in order to convert to different units.
SimpleDateFormat is one class which can perform the conversion.

To do this create a 'SimpleDateFormat' class, pass the String representation in, and call 'getTime'

> val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
>
> val milliseconds = format.parse(desiredTime).getTime

This makes various assumptions about time zones and calendars. Further details on the SimpleDateFormat available here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

The following method will give you milliseconds.

```
new Date(desiredTime).getTime()
```